# Replacing two 2" x 12" - 24 (span) with comparable strength LVL beam

Tags: lumber

I'm the GC for my home palapa (covered patio) project.  No walls, with 4 posts to support a 20' x 24'roof (metal roof).  My framer gave me a B.O.M. of 4 each 2"x 12"-24 feet and 4 each 2"x12"-20 feet, plus many other pcs.  I'm sure his experience he knows what is needed.  2 12" together for each of the 20 foot and 24 foot roof beams.  My question is I prefer to use LVL.  It's straighter, resists twist, and stronger.  Since it's stronger, can't I use smaller? verses using two at 1.5lvl at standard 1.75" x 11.87"?  Seems like an overkill.  Where can I find load tables so I can compare two 2"x 12" at 20' and at 24' spans to lvl beams?  Point me to links and data so I can review with him and make him comfortable as well.  I'm buying the materials and paying him for the labor to frame the roof.  thanks,

Comment: The manufacture for your LVL beams should have span/load tables for their product.  For example I have the "LP SolidStart LVL Technical Guide" in my reference collection.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to see a sketch or drawing showing the post/beam/rafter locations.

Comment: And finally, what part of the country are you in?  Do you have the dead+live load numbers or your area?

Comment: I have used the makers "in house" engineers to calculate my span issues on 2 jobs in the past. Call the maker of the LVL and tell them the span, the loads and anything else they may need and they will tell you what you need to know. For me, I would stick with the 11 7/8" and go over kill. Engineers always go over kill

Comment: I agree with jack at 11-7/8 you could spread out and go 24 OC but I Don’t like flex in the roofing a 9-1/2 won’t make the span , the tables I looked at are for my area and yes 11-7/8 is over the top as far as requirements but you would need to drop down to 12” OC to make a 20’ span with 9-1/2”